# Neither clang nor g++ compile the snippet below. Why?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, member-access

Neither `clang` nor `g++` compile [this snippet](https://godbolt.org/g/3ttxIV):

```
struct A{
protected:    
    struct B{};
};

struct D: A::B, A{};
```

According to [[class.access]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#7), we have:

> Similarly, the use of A::B as a base-specifier is well-formed because
>   D is derived from A, so checking of base-specifiers must be deferred
>   until the entire base-specifier-list has been seen.

The example and the sentence above are part of [class.access]/7, at least since C++11.

Comment: Because both clang and gcc are programs, written by people, who are not perfect. This is a bug in both compilers. [Edit: and also in VC++ http://rextester.com/DSGF74287 ]

Comment: An obvious common compiler bug. The specification is unambiguous.

Comment: @StoryTeller But at least VS2015 compiles the code if the _base-specifier_ `A` comes before the _base-specifier_ `A::B`.

Comment: What can I say, the VS people got something right ;)

Comment: This compiles as-is with VS2015 update 3.